# How can I name a layer?

Tags: customization, layers

Can I name the layers with customized names, or something like that? If not, is it possible to add different colors to every single box?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot do such modifications in the layers table of the 3d window header.

***Solution:*** Enable the ***Layer Name*** addon.
[image]

You can then change the layers names. You'll find the *Layer Managment* tab in the *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>).
[image]

Comment: I use Blender 2.79, but the Layer Name addon is not there. Can I download it online? Maybe you're using an older version of Blender.